# debate: Is adding third party libraries to a war a good idea?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, jar, package

We have a debate going on .

a.  The "standard" way of  assembling a web app. 
     Create a WAR with all our app artifacts and all other components like hibernate and memcached etc are deployed in the tomcat/shared/lib area.

b.  Create a humongous war with everything included and nothing in tomcat/shared/lib.

Pros for a - It keeps things modular and the war is small.
Cons for a - dependency on shared/lib has to be managed especially by the deployment process.

Pros for b - All dependencies are controlled by the build process removing any room for error.
Cons for b - War is really, really big. If you are deploying over a network to a huge farm, then it might have an impact.

want to see what thoughts others might have about this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I thought B was the "standard" way :-)

I choose B nearly all the time. It's simpler for our customers - many of whom don't have skills administering java application servers - they just drop the WAR in to the place I tell them to and everything works.

It also works well with our build and deploy - the WAR is built using maven, so all necessary dependencies are included, and also can be deployed to our QA app servers using the cargo plugin.

It also avoids "WAR-hell" when you have several webapps requiring hibernate or some other dependency, but different versions.

I would choose A only when I cam in total control of the app server, and the overhead of duplicating the common libraries per webapp becames prohibitively large, or that I am able to ensure all the apps are tested with the same version of the dependencies. Then, I know the dependencies can be safely moved into the shared area of the app server.

Comment: Interesting. we are in total control of the server. 
You make good points  but what about wanting to avoid having multiple versions of the same component in different webapps.Is that not a desirable objective from a ops/mgmt perspective? I am routinely finding multiple versions of XML parsers etc for no reason  other than that it was not discouraged.

Comment: I agree with you - if you are in control of the apps and the server, then strive for convergence on the versions of 3rd party libraries. I use maven, which helps a lot with this. Even so, I see it as a version management issue rather than a deployment issue. That all apps have been tested with the same version of a lib means that lib can be shared, but the version management has to come first to pave the way for shared libs to be possible.

Comment: Yep, I agree.  We use Maven to manage that. 
But there is some thought to moving  to a single war and we are debating whether it is worth to change and are there benefits which others might have seen.